# Change target platform for Visual Studio 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2008, x86, 64-bit, oledb

I am using 64-bit Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008 Express for my website in C#. And the database I used was OLEDB (Access in .mdb format). It worked well on my PC. But when I published it using [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) on the server, it showed me the following error:

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

On searching for the error on Google, I realized the problem was due to build in 64-bit (if I am not wrong), for which I needed to change my target platform to x86 from AnyCPU. But since I am using the Express version, this option is not available.

Some suggested editing .csproj manually after unloading the project from Visual Studio. But again this option is also not available due to the Express version.

What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately platform processor settings not seems to be a VS Express feature...in this article is told clearly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b4eyb0k.aspx.....when i had this kind of problems i used to compile on my work machine (uses VS2008 Professional) instead of my home machine (uses vs2008 express)..have you tried to use vs2010 express? Maybe this feature is unlocked...hope it helps...